# The ('form').submit() is not firing up

Tags: php, jquery

I am having trouble to submit my form as .submit() in jquery is not being fired. Can anyone help me? Here is part of my code...

```
<form id="repmsg" class="remember" method="post" action="test.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="filepj" id="message_file" class="message_file f_left" style="float: left;"/>
<input type="submit" style="display: none" name="pj" id="pj1">
</form>
<a onclick="sendMessage(<?php echo $mId; ?>);" href="javascript:;" class="envoyer_reponse f_right"><?php echo $translate->translate('send'); ?><span><span></span></span></a>
        <a onclick="cancelMessage(<?php echo $mId; ?>);" href="javascript:;" class="annuler_reponse f_right"><?php echo $translate->translate('wish_popup_annuler'); ?></a>
```

When i click on the link sendMessage, a jquery function is fired. Here is the sendMessage() function

```
function sendMessage(id) {

var mId = id;

if( $('#msg_txt_'+id).val() != '' ) {

    var message_file = $('#message_file').val();

    uploads();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        data: { mId: id, type: 1, message: $("#msg_txt_"+id).val(), act:"rep", msg_file : message_file},
        url: path_relative_root+'message-detail.php',
        success: function( response ){

            if( response == '1' ) {
                $('#msg_conf_'+mId).html(message_send);
                $('#msg_conf_'+mId).show();
            }
            else {
                $('#msg_conf_'+mId).html(message_fail);
                $('#msg_conf_'+mId).show();
            }

        }
    });

}
else

    $('#msg_conf_'+mId).hide();

}
```

From this sendMessage() function, there is an upload() function which will have the .submit()

```
function uploads(){

var message_file = $('#message_file').val();

console.log(message_file);

if( message_file != '' ){

    console.log('test');

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $( "#repmsg" ).submit(function( e ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            data = new FormData($("#repmsg")[0]);

            console.log('Submitting');

            alert('hello');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: path_relative_root + 'message-detail.php',
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
            }).done(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, status, errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown);
                console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
                console.log(jqXHR.status);
            });

        });
    });
}

}
```

Can someone please help me find my mistakes, why i can't submit my form.Thanks

Comment: Because of `e.preventDefault`?

Comment: From where you are calling `uploads()`?

Comment: Should i remove the e.preventDefault? lolka_bolka

Comment: Why is `document.ready` inside uploads function?

Comment: Yes i am calling from uploads...Is this valid to call a form.submit(0 from inside a jquery function?

Comment: I have google and found that document.ready solved this problem for others.Thats why i added it in my code. @Deepak Kumar Padhy

Comment: `preventDefault ` should not stop jQuery functions in your handler. Anything logged in console?

Comment: And how do you try to submit the form? The submit button is hidden and in your code you are binding submit event on each anchor click, not triggering it

Comment: In console it hangs on test as it is just above the form.submit()....

Comment: I cannot really, im currently on tablet so hard to post an answer but you are really missing some basics. See how bind event and the fire it

Comment: AGAIN you arent submiting the FORM  anywhere in your code AND the submit button is hidden so hard to believe you can click on it

Comment: The path_relative_root has been defined as a Constant in some config file. @MasterSlave

Comment: The problem is not with the IF() condition as it still persist even after i removed the if() condition. The `$( "#repmsg" ).submit(function( e )` itself is n ot being fired as in the log, it did not print 'Submitting'

Comment: this will never fire, it only binds the submit event, look at the A. Wolff's comment, remove the $( "#repmsg" ).submit(function( e ) {e.preventDefault(); live just the ajax call and it will be OK

Comment: this might help https://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery

Comment: Yes it will work if i live only the ajax call...but i can't get the file uploaded in the form. in my message-detail.php when i make a print_r($_FILES) it return me an empty array(). @MasterSlave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came across something similar recently. I don't think it should matter, may be a bug but try

`data: $("#repmsg").serialize()`

instead of

`data = new FormData($("#repmsg")[0]);`

Comment: Still not working after changing to 'data: $("#repmsg").serialize()' @Marcell Fulop